# "Left overspeed" on MD-11

Tags: cockpit-alerts, md-11

The MD-11 has an overspeed and a left overspeed call-out alarms. This is different from the modern planes counterparts, in which a tick-tick-tick sound is used instead.

What does left overspeed even mean and why is there no right overspeed?

Comment: Where do you see the MD-11 "left" overspeed mentioned?

Comment: I heard (now with the fabulous answer I should say misheard) it in https://invidious.protokolla.fi/watch?v=TK5K9pJo67w.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misheard that: it doesn't say "left overspeed", but "**slat** overspeed", when the maximum speed with slats extended is exceeded.

You can hear the call out e.g. in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/0L6DtWo4mJ0?t=13). The MD-11 FCOM doesn't explicitly list the call outs, but it explains that both overspeed conditions result in an aural alarm:

> **Overspeed Warnings**
>
> The CAWS will provide an aural warning tone when an overspeed condition is
> detected by either Central Air Data Computer (CADC). The CAWS will also
> provide an aural warning whenever the aircraft exceeds the maximum speed with
> the slats extended.

<sup>(McDonnell Douglas MD-11 FCOM - Warning and Alerting - Description and Operation)</sup>

The "slat overspeed" is however explicitly mentioned in the final accident report of [China Eastern flight 583](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19930406-2):

> The captain [...] observed the white "SLAT" light with a down arrow illuminate on
> the PFD [...] and, at the same time, the "slat overspeed" warning chime
> sounded.

<sup>([NTSB Aircraft Accident Report - China Eastern flight 583](https://reports.aviation-safety.net/1993/19930406-2_MD11_B-2171.pdf))</sup>

By the way, the "tick-tick-tick sound" you describe is created by the **clacker**, which is used at least since the 1960s (so I wouldn't call it the modern counterpart). The MD-11 also has a clacker:

> The clacker will sound when airspeed exceeds 280 knots and
> the slats are extended. [...]
>
> **Overspeed**
>
> AURAL - clacker.
>
> - Logic - airspeed above Vmo/Vmo plus 4 KTS or above 280 KTS with
>   slats extended.
> - Inhibit - takeoff (80 KTS to 400’ RA) and landing (100’ RA to 80 KTS).
>
> VISUAL - red and white bar on airspeed tape on PFD.
>
> - Logic - airspeed above Vmo/Vmo plus 4 KTS.
> - Inhibit - none.

<sup>(McDonnell Douglas MD-11 FCOM - Warning and Alerting - Description and Operation)</sup>